# What form of ID do I have as a foreign student in France?

Tags: france, student-visa, identification

I am currently a senior and will soon apply for my French Visa for my studies in France, I know that they will stick this large visa in my passport as it's my main way to enter and exit France however on a daily basis, what can I use as an ID? I'm sure as hell ain't gonna take my passport everywhere I go, and the ID issued in my home country is not in English. Do I get a *carte de séjour* or is that something else?

Comment: As a foreigner, you are required, apon demand, to prove your legal status in the Schengen Area. Until you receive your residence permit (which is a plastic card in most cases), your passport is that proof. In Spain, you are required to have this proof with with you **at all times**. In others it is less stringent, but you can be detained at the discretion of the authorities if you don't have the proof with you.

Comment: The **carte Sejour** is the residence permit card. But it often takes a long time into it actually issued.

Comment: @MarkJohnson It's perfectly legitimate for nationals and non-nationals alike to question unreasonable laws. Protesting is allowed too and even civil disobedience should not expose anybody to disproportionnate punishment.

Comment: @Relaxed There will be many who will believe that it is disproportionate for a *guest* in someone elses home to determine what is considered reasonable or not. How one behaves in someone elses home are things that parents teach their children. The OP should remember these lessons before deciding to enter.

Comment: @MarkJohnson “Guest” is the ugly German word for people who happen to be non-citizens. Your comment epitomizes the thinking behind that word but really justifies nothing. The notion that some people are not entitled to aspirations, feelings, opinions or political activity, should only leave their country if they are prepared to be treated and behave like children or that the country they live in is forever not their own is legally and morally baseless. And “proportionate” to what? That's a notion that only comes into evaluating government action, especially punishment, what does it mean here?

Comment: @Relaxed Obeying the law does not preclude the fulfillment of the goals of a visitor. Even your 'imaginative' redefinition of the word 'Guest' (see ['guest worker', 'Gastarbeiter', 'gastarbeider', 'arbetskraftsinvandring', 'гастарбайтер'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastarbeiter)) is no excuse for bad mannors and the ignoring local customs and laws.

Comment: @MarkJohnson Obeying the law is generally a good idea for foreigners and citizens alike, that's not what's at stake here but the notion that non-citizens are “guests” who should accept a position of inferiority and not have a say or opinion on what's reasonable or not. You can in fact do both at the same time. And, yes, the word *Gastarbeiter* is exactly what I was referring to, no redefinition here...

Comment: @Relaxed Then you should read the Wikipedia article to learn what is understood by  that term, that differs greatly from your understanding of it.

Comment: @Relaxed After that, you can then concentrate on the original comment in the context that was intended (good behaviour that parents teach their children).

Comment: @MarkJohnson I am well aware of the context and there is nothing in there that contradicts what I wrote, just as the subtext of your comments was very clear. It is still offensive, whether you realize it or not.

Comment: @MarkJohnson indeed, the paternalistic attitude towards immigrants, holding them out as "children" who must be "taught," is offensive.  Remember that the immigration system does not only exist for the benefit of the immigrant, but also for the benefit of the country, which has no obligation to admit foreigners as workers or as students.  Then again, searching online for German texts about hospitality, I find many articles about how Germans lack it, and none about how to cultivate it, so perhaps that lack of hospitality underlies this discussion.

Comment: @phoog Most children have allready learned their basic good mannors. The topic here is about those, even before they arrive, that don't have the intension of respecting local laws - expressed through the statement: **I'm sure as hell ain't gonna ...**. No one is above the law.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, students get what is called a *visa long séjour valant titre de séjour* (VLS/TS) and in principle you do need to carry that with you to be able to prove your right to reside in France. You would not get a *carte de séjour* immediately but only apply for one at the end of your first year in France.

Not having it is not a criminal offense and you cannot be punished for it but the police is allowed to keep you up to 24 hours while they check your status. If they are reasonable, they might let you recover the passport and present it to them but it's not a given. Carrying other semi-official documents like a student card from your university might also help (or it might not). And depending on how you look and where you live, police checks are not unlikely so carrying your passport might be necessary to avoid a whole lot of hassle.

If you do get a *carte de séjour* then using that is fine, you don't need a passport or any other sort of identification as that's not mandatory in France. Some members of my family lived in France for many years using only that, without even renewing their passport.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, your ID outside of your home country (where you are a citizen) should be your (travel) passport. So, you need to use it "on a daily basis".

An ID and visa are different things. You might need to identify yourself to many people (bank, hospital, ticket controller in the train, post office and so on), but most of them do not have the right to check your visa or residence permit, which is usually also not an ID on its own.

AFAIK, the article L611-1 of the [Code for Entry and Residence of Foreigners in France and the Right of Asylum](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do?idSectionTA=LEGISCTA000006134417&cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006070158) requires all foreigners in France to permanently carry an ID with them. However, I never lived in France and cannot provide any details on how exactly is it in practice.

Comment: L611-1-1 is also relavent, since it contains the conditions of possible containment (24 hours, fingerprinting and notification of public prosecuter etc.).

Comment: That's not what L611-1-1 is about, you need a proof of your legal status, not ID. It is never mandatory to carry any form of identification in France. That might not help the OP immediately but that means in particular that a *carte de séjour* is sufficient.